# Arduino SD card reader creating files but not writing to them with Nokia GLCD

Tags: arduino, sd-card, lcd

I have been busy on this for a few days and I have come up empty at every turn.
a simple temp logging device is what Im trying to create.

I have a working code for creating and writing to files using the serial monitor this works great but the moment I bring it into contact with any other devices ( Im using switches to navigat an LCD display it fails on the writing part)

The code will create a file with the name I choose but will not write to that file This is my problem

here is my code.

```
// Date and time functions using a DS1307 RTC connected via I2C and Wire lib
//A4 -- SDA
//A5 -- SCL
// 2 -- DS ///// Not needed really I dont think

// It is assumed that the LCD module is connected to
// the following pins using a levelshifter to get the
// correct voltage to the module.
//      SCK  - Pin 0
//      MOSI - Pin 1
//      DC   - Pin 2
//      RST  - Pin 3
//      CS   - Pin 5 
//
/*

 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13

 ** CS - pin 10

 */


#include <LCD5110_Graph.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

LCD5110 myGLCD(0,1,2,3,5);
RTC_DS1307 RTC;
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];
extern uint8_t TinyFont[];
int up=6,down=8,enter=4,right=7,left=9; ////worked out new ones
File root;
char fileName[12];

void setup()  
{
  Wire.begin();
  RTC.begin();
  myGLCD.InitLCD();
  myGLCD.clrScr();
  myGLCD.setFont(SmallFont);

   while (! RTC.isrunning()) 
      {
        myGLCD.print("RTC NOT running!",CENTER,18);
        myGLCD.update();
        Wire.begin();
        RTC.begin();
      }  
    myGLCD.print("RTC NOW running!",CENTER,18);
    myGLCD.update();
    delay(1000);
    myGLCD.clrScr();
    myGLCD.print("Start",CENTER,18);
    myGLCD.update();
    delay(1000);

  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

if (!SD.begin(10)) 
{
  myGLCD.print("FAILED!",CENTER,18);
  myGLCD.update();
  delay(1000);
}
else
{
myGLCD.print("DONE",CENTER,18);
myGLCD.update();
delay(1000);
}
  pinMode(up,INPUT);
  pinMode(down,INPUT);
  pinMode(enter,INPUT);
  pinMode(left,INPUT);
  pinMode(right,INPUT);
  pinMode (A0,INPUT);


}

void loop()
{
myGLCD.print("Names now",CENTER,18);
myGLCD.update();
delay(1000);

menu();

float Temp

root = SD.open(fileName,FILE_WRITE);
DateTime now = RTC.now();

if(root) {
  for(int p=0;p<5;p++)
{
   myGLCD.print("DONE 2",CENTER,18);
   myGLCD.update();

   delay(1000);

   /////////// Code to get the current temp
   Temp = log(((34611200/analogRead(A0)) - 33800));
   Temp = 1 / (0.000815883 + (0.000222435 * Temp) + (0.000000104 * Temp * Temp * Temp));
   Temp = Temp - 273.15;            // Convert Kelvin to Celcius


   myGLCD.clrScr();
   myGLCD.print("Temp",CENTER,18);

  myGLCD.update();

  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
    root.print(Temp);
    root.print(" ---- ");
    root.print(now.hour());
    root.print(":");
    root.print(now.minute());
    root.print(" ");
    root.print(now.day());
    root.print("/");
    root.print(now.month());
    root.print("/");
    root.println(now.year());
  delay(2000);
}

  root.close();   
}
else {
  myGLCD.print("Failed",CENTER,18);
  myGLCD.update();
  delay(1000);
}
root.close();
  }

void menu()
{
//////////// menu to select what you want to do (create a file)
/// then goes to picker to select name
}
void picker()
{
//// code to put a selection for a file name on the LCD USER selects this file name after that 
////////// .txt is added to the name
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this already, but if it helps, I've done something similar with displaying indoor/outdoor temperatures on an LCD. I made a post about it on G+ here https://plus.google.com/102008088829487106625/posts/cKodZMchrUB

I also just started logging data to an SD card today, the working code is here: https://github.com/Elucidation/ArduinoTemperatureMonitor/tree/SD_logging

Hopefully between all that you'll get what you need to solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks man I had already completed the problem but I will look into what you have said thanks a lot.

Comment: ans what was your solution?